# Interact with user's file system

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, web-applications

I'm working on web application that deals with files of different kinds and stores it's metadata (e. g. if it is Microsoft Word file, then I try to parse it, if JPEG - EXIF, and so on).

General workflow: the user selects a file stored in a database, presses check out file, then default user editor / viewer (e. g. for PSD - Adobe Photoshop) will be opened on user's PC. When user finishes working on file, she presses check in and web application uploads file for further post-processing.

Right know this workflow implemented using Mozilla Firefox AddOn SDK (particularly *sdk/io/file* and *OS.File* methods): web application interacts with an extension for downloading / uploading file. So my application is tied to Firefox. But guys from Mozilla is working on WebExtensions API and I'm afraid in future they will deprecate AddOn SDK at all. Unfortunately, WebExtensions API doesn't provide functions for interacting with a file system.

So my question is: is there any other ways to interact with file system from web application? May be WebAssembly will provide such capabilities (bad luck, due lack of documentation, I can not find any sensible information about it)? Anyway I want to write application that will be compatible with major browsers, so I don't want to deal with extensions / addons anymore.